# How to save data to google document using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-docs, google-docs-api

I want to save some data to google document (doc. not google spreadsheet).
I have two input fields. One takes input as email while other one takes input as mobile no. I want to save those data as following to goole doc.

ex:-
    someone@email.com|9086458212

Here is the [doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W0swizgXUIsdmZmy-U3sdQs4ZX3f2Sr6marlibQwIRQ/edit?usp=sharing).

NOTE : I know how to save data to spreadsheet.

Comment: unlikely to be possible with pure js

Comment: Add the code that would save to the spreadsheet, that you know how to do.  Are you using Apps Script?  Or is this a non-Google Sites website?